# Android: the best way to store and array, clear on app close

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite, internal-storage

What would be the best way to store an array { devicename, macaddress, updated } in an android application and then dispose of the data once a user closes the app.

**UPDATE:** By store, i mean using SQLite, Internal Storage (create file then delete) etc. is there any best practice to do this, the reason for asking is because i will need to access the data rather than call an API each time.

I only ask as i am new to Android development.

Comment: I'd serialize it to a string (using the **join** method with a separator char). Then deserialize the string by using the **split** method and get the array back.

Comment: Referencing the [lifecycle guide](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html), by "user closes the app" do you mean when `onStop()` is called or when `onDestroy()` is called - or something else?

Comment: Use JsonArray to store name value pair

Comment: By store i mean utilizing SQLite, internal storage etc?

Comment: From your question, it sounds like you only want the data to persist while the app is running. Why do you need to write to "disk" at all?  As @user3464143 mentioned, a private instance of an Array like class seems to be exactly what you want - it can be created and initialized at startup, and it then goes away when your Activity / Service / Broadcast Receiver is ultimately destroyed.

Comment: This is why i was asking for the best way, or suggestions on how to do this ;) I thought about storing the device details (not phone details, a 3rd party/external device) in case the signal was weak, thus reducing the amount of calls on the API i am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A private instance of an Array or Map like object seems to be exactly what you need. Based on your question and the comments above, I see no reason to involve non-volatile storage or fancy Map objects.

Borrowing a bit from the [android developer docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html), and assuming you are implementing an Activity in your app, your code could look something like this:

```java
...

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

....

public class ExampleActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String TAG = "ExampleActivity";

    // create an enum to hold your key values (plain old strings could work too)
    private enum ApiKey {
        NAME, MAC, UPDATED
    };

    //declare your data structure
    private Map<ApiKey, String> myCachedApiData;   

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // The activity is being created.

        // initialize your data in onCreate()
        myCachedApiData = new HashMap<ApiKey, String>();

        // retrieve initial data from your API
        // you may want to do this on another thread if it takes a while

        ...

        // put data in your map
        myCachedApiData.put( ApiKey.NAME, deviceNameStr );
        myCachedApiData.put( ApiKey.MAC, macAddressStr );
        myCachedApiData.put( ApiKey.UPDATED, updatedStr );
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // The activity is about to become visible, lets
        // print out (access) some of our cached API data
        // each time the user views our Activity

        Log.d( TAG, "MAC addr is: " + myCachedApiData.get( ApiKey.MAC ) );

    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // The activity has become visible (it is now "resumed").
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // Another activity is taking focus (this activity is about to be "paused").
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // The activity is no longer visible (it is now "stopped")
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // The activity is about to be destroyed.

        // No need to explicitly clear our map, it will be removed when our
        // Activity is destroyed

        // myCachedApiData.clear();
    }
}
```